# XML continuously updating values

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm trying to get a program to continuously write data to an XML node in a file but I'm not sure how to implement it. The XML file is a Google Earth kml file that needs coordinates in order to draw a path:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <Style>
      <LineStyle>
        <color>7f00ffff</color>
        <width>4</width>
      </LineStyle>
    </Style>
    <Placemark>
      <LineString>
        <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
        <coordinates>0,0,0</coordinates>
      </LineString>
    </Placemark>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

I only need to modify the coordinates node and add subsequent lines. This would be accomplished using a timer to write a new set of coordinates every second. This will probably have hundreds of lines:

```
<coordinates> 
      -112.2550785337791,36.07954952145647,2357
      -112.2549277039738,36.08117083492122,2357
      -112.2552505069063,36.08260761307279,2357
      -112.2564540158376,36.08395660588506,2357
      -112.2580238976449,36.08511401044813,2357
      -112.2595218489022,36.08584355239394,2357

(...etc)

</coordinates>
```

I'm not quite understanding how to go about accessing just the coordinates node and write value after value. I've tried something like this but it's not working:

```
  XmlDocument dataFile = new XmlDocument();
  dataFile.Load("gpsData.kml");

  XmlNode node = dataFile.SelectSingleNode("kml/Document/Placemark/LineString/coordinates");

  node.InnerText (?) <- how do I append new text instead of replacing the whole thing?
```

Comment: Do you *have* to use XmlDocument? COuld you use LINQ to XML instead?

Comment: `node.InnerText = node.InnerText + myOtherText`?

Answer (score 0):

Just whipped this up. Not sure if there's a faster way to accomplish the same thing. Works for me, though.

```
using System;
using System.Timers;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {

            var fileName = "C:\\gpsData.kml";

            var xml = XDocument.Load(fileName);
            var xmlns = xml.Root.Name.Namespace;
            var document = xml.Root.Element(xmlns.GetName("Document"));
            var placemark = document.Element(xmlns.GetName("Placemark"));
            var lineString = placemark.Element(xmlns.GetName("LineString"));
            var coordinates = lineString.Element(xmlns.GetName("coordinates"));

            var inc = 0;
            var timer = new Timer();
            var timer_Elapsed = new ElapsedEventHandler((s, e) => {

                // get the new coordinate here
                var newCoordinate = "-112.2550785337791,36.07954952145647,2357";
                var oldValue = coordinates.Value;
                var newValue = oldValue + Environment.NewLine + newCoordinate;
                coordinates.Value = newValue;

                xml.Save(fileName);

                inc++;
            });

            timer.Interval = 1000;
            timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
            timer.Start();

            while (10 > inc) ;

            timer.Stop();
            timer.Elapsed -= timer_Elapsed;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to rewrite the whole XML file each time. There is no way to just update a part of an XML file. As the file grows, the process will slow down successively. Consider using a plain text file instead.

```cs
File.AppendAllText(path, newText);
```

or (starting from .NET 4.0)

```cs
File.AppendAllLines(path, stringEnumeration);
```

You could also reference this text file from within the XML file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <Document>
    <Style>
      <LineStyle>
        <color>7f00ffff</color>
        <width>4</width>
      </LineStyle>
    </Style>
    <Placemark>
      <LineString>
        <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
        <coordinates xlink:href="http://mysite.com/data/coordinates.txt"/>
      </LineString>
    </Placemark>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

Comment: I'll take a look at this approach too. Thanks Oliver!